# Angularjs Selectbox with remote data and no empty value

Tags: angularjs

I have a common problem with selectboxes in angularjs, when I retrieve the options and the model from REST api.

This is my html which is inside a ng-repeat:

```
<select class="form-control"
    name="{{ field.name }}"
    ng-model="data[field.name]"
    ng-options="key as value for (key, value) in field.options">
</select>
```

In the controller I retrieve both - the $scope.field value and the $scope.data value from a (REST) service. The data basically looks like this:

```
data = {
    'selectfield' => 2
};
field = {
    'name' => 'selectfield',
    'options' => {
        '1': 'Option 1',
        '2': 'Option 2'
    }
};
```

The problem: I get an empty option for this selectbox and this empty value is selected, even if the data.selectfield has another value. What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

Your select is bound to the value of `data[field.name]`. So it default value will be the value of `data[field.name]` which is `selectfield`. (And not its value)

You should change the expression in `ng-model="data[field.name]"` to the variable's name you would like to bound the select.
For example in your case if `data` is also a $scope variable:

```
ng-model="data.selectfield"
```

Comment: But the point is, that I get both from the server - the data as well as the field variable. So I don't know in the template, how the field is called, thats why I am using data[field.name]